# AVExportSession with a streaming AVAsset -11800 Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, avfoundation

I have been using AVPlayer to play video where the underlying asset that is backed by a Streaming URL.

I am trying to create a snip of the video (just a 9 second clip), in order to save the clip locally.

I tried AVAssetExportSession with the following code, but the session returns AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed every time.  The specific error is Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800, which means unknown error.

```
AVURLAsset *otherAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:streamURL options:options];

NSArray *exportPresets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:otherAsset];
NSLog(exportPresets.description);

AVAssetExportSession *session = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:otherAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
NSArray *supportedFileTypes = session.supportedFileTypes;
NSLog(supportedFileTypes.description);


NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString *dstPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/sample.mov"];
NSURL *savetUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dstPath];

session.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
session.outputURL = savetUrl;

session.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

[session exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(void ) {


     switch ([session status]) {
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
             NSLog([session error].description);
             NSLog(@"Export failed: %@",[[session error]localizedDescription]);
             break;
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
             NSLog(@"Export canceled");
             break;
         default:
             NSLog(@"Export Success, File Saved.");
             break;
     }
 }
 ];
```

I've checked to make sure that I am not overwriting a file, and checked other causes of AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed.

I am guessing that AVAssetExportSession is not meant to be used with streaming assets. (I could be wrong).

Is my guess right, or is there something else I need to do.  Is there an easier way to snip and cache a streaming URL?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

For as far as I know, there is no way to export other than local files under iOS7.

It seems to work fine under iOS8 though.

I suggest you just use NSData.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: bool) if you don't have to set an exportInterval.

Hope this'll help!